# Trying to write data to database in Laravel

Tags: php, laravel

I'm trying to write data to my database. I need to write user auth data and user input data. How do you combine that well? I did it before without user auth data; I documented that code. With my new code, I'm getting this error:

> Method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::create does not exist.

```
public function store(Request $request)
{
      $dataInput = $request ->all();
      $user = Auth::user();
      $user->notebooks->create($dataInput);
      //Notebook::create($dataInput);

      return redirect('/notebooks');
}
```

**model User**

```
class User extends Authenticatable
{
    use Notifiable;

    protected $fillable = [
        'name', 'email', 'password',
    ];

    protected $hidden = [
        'password', 'remember_token',
    ];

    protected $casts = [
        'email_verified_at' => 'datetime',
    ];

    public function notebooks(){
        return $this ->hasMany(Notebook::class);
    }
}
```

**model Notebook**

```
class Notebook extends Model
{
    protected $fillable =['name'];
}
```

Comment: a subtle change `$user->notebooks()->create($dataInput);`. assuming the user model has a notebooks() method

Comment: @Mentally Unstable Schizomaniac please share your model

Comment: I added models to question